# Moving one TextBox causes all TextBoxes and Labels to move

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, github

I am working on a windowsforms vb.net app in visual studio 2019 and today I suddenly started experiecing a strange issue when moving controls.

On one form, whenever I move one textbox, it immediatly snaps back into almost its origional position and all the other textboxes and lables on the form move & re-size slightly. On other forms I can move controls but it move everything else slightly too. When I look at the form designer code it goes from this before:

```
  'SpecsButton
        '
        Me.SpecsButton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.SpecsButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(194, 25)
        Me.SpecsButton.Name = "SpecsButton"
        Me.SpecsButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(141, 44)
        Me.SpecsButton.TabIndex = 113
        Me.SpecsButton.Text = "Specs"
        Me.SpecsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'CastButton
        '
        Me.CastButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
        Me.CastButton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.CastButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(28, 25)
        Me.CastButton.Name = "CastButton"
        Me.CastButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(147, 44)
        Me.CastButton.TabIndex = 112
        Me.CastButton.Text = "Casts"
        Me.CastButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button3
        '
        Me.Button3.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
        Me.Button3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Button3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(103, 97)
        Me.Button3.Name = "Button3"
        Me.Button3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(154, 42)
        Me.Button3.TabIndex = 111
        Me.Button3.Text = "Exit"
        Me.Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
```

And changes to this after moving one button:

```
SpecsButton
        '
        Me.SpecsButton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.SpecsButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(129, 16)
        Me.SpecsButton.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2)
        Me.SpecsButton.Name = "SpecsButton"
        Me.SpecsButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(94, 29)
        Me.SpecsButton.TabIndex = 113
        Me.SpecsButton.Text = "Specs"
        Me.SpecsButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'CastButton
        '
        Me.CastButton.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
        Me.CastButton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.CastButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(27, 30)
        Me.CastButton.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2)
        Me.CastButton.Name = "CastButton"
        Me.CastButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(98, 29)
        Me.CastButton.TabIndex = 112
        Me.CastButton.Text = "Casts"
        Me.CastButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button3
        '
        Me.Button3.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.System
        Me.Button3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Button3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(69, 63)
        Me.Button3.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2)
        Me.Button3.Name = "Button3"
        Me.Button3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(103, 27)
        Me.Button3.TabIndex = 111
        Me.Button3.Text = "Exit"
        Me.Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
```

I am completely baffled at how moving one thing is changing the size, location and in some cases padding of everything else on the form.

What I have tried so far:

- Looking for any differences in the settings of the controls. Locked is not set to true or anything like that. Auto scaling is set to font.
- Tried moving the textbox using the keyboard arrows or alignment tools
- The repo is stored on GitHub and the other contributor is not having this issue. Syncing with their working copy didn't solve the problem and neither did deleting all the local files and re-downloading them from GitHub. They are also using visual studio 2019
- Turned the computer off and on again
- Reinstalled visual studio then tried the Beta version
- Starting a new project - still had the same issue

To make maters worse, when I try to undo the changes, it doesn't put things back to where they were originally and actually moves them more!

I've taken some screenshots - First one is after trying to move one label:

[image: First]

and the second one is after clicking undo, and everything has jumbled up:

[image: Second]

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful as right now this is making Visual Studio unusable.

Comment: Can you add the type of Framework (right, should be .Net Framework, but add it anyway), Visual Studio version (your contributor's, too), `AutoscaleMode` (not visible here) and the high DPI/Font scaling settings in your machines?

Comment: Hi, Autoscalemode is set to font on both computers. I have tried changing it and it doesn’t make any difference. The Win8DpiScaling just says 0x00000000 (0) on both computers.